# Black spots on gooseberry leaves

Tags: diagnosis, diseases, leaves

I have gooseberry/red currant plant (grafted).

A some point black spots appeared on gooseberry leaves. They appear overnight on more mature leaves. Red currant leaves does not seem to be affected in any way.

Do you know why is it happening and how I can deal with that?

Thank you in advance!

[image: Black spots on goosberry leaves]

[image: Black spots on goosberry leaves]